# Wordpress: prevent code dupplication through similar page templates

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, refactoring

I'm currently doing some refactoring on an existing wordpress website that uses 9 page templates and I have the following problem:

All these pages have the same code written to display the header, the sidebar etc.

I wonder if it's possible for me to have a "parent" page that would be in charge of displaying those recurring template parts?

The reason I can't manage to do it is that only the page template file is called and no parent file.

That's what I would like to achieve:

```
<?php
  // page-master.php
  get_header();
  get_sidebar();
  get_page_content(); // includes the actual page template.
  get_footer();
?>
```

I hope you understand what I'm looking for :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create template your-name.php
Put that code

```
<?php
  /*
  Template Name: Your Name
  /*
  get_header();
  get_sidebar();
  get_template_part(template-hepler/your-name-content.php); // includes the actual page template.
  get_footer();
?>
```

Create your-name-content.php in template-helper folder
And write there your page content
Assing that template to nessasary pages

Comment: That's what I did and it solved my problem. Thanks! :)